# Laravel returning the same view for 2 different routes

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel is somehow getting the same view for 2 different routes and I can't figure out why since I'm not very familiar with Laravel.

Here's the 2 routes in question :

```
Route::get('/{label}', [BookController::class, 'listbyCat'])->name('bycats');

Route::get('/{id}', [BookController::class, 'singlebook'])->name('book');
```

The first route is the one returning the view (calling the method), that means if I switch between them it wall call singlebook() in both routes.

HTML :

```
 <a href="{{ route('book', $book->id) }}">Book</a>

 <a href="{{ route('bycats', $cat->id) }}">Category</a>
```

Comment: Both routes have just a parameter, how should laravel tell the difference between a label and an id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to access any resource you gonna write the route on the browser
so what if i just had two resources like those:

```
Route::get('/book/{label}', [BookController::class, 'listbyCat'])->name('bycats');

Route::get('/book/{id}', [BookController::class, 'singlebook'])->name('book');
```

And i am trying to access `localhost::8080/book/5`

So what tells laravel from this route that this route belongs to which one of the resources ?

Nothing !!
Cause `5` could be considered as a `label` or `id`

So you should change the route to be identifiable to laravel

Try to change one of the routes, Example:

```
Route::get('/book/by/{label}', [BookController::class, 'listbyCat'])->name('bycats');

Route::get('/book/{id}', [BookController::class, 'singlebook'])->name('book');
```

Comment: Yeah I figured so. But there's another problem I ran into, the views contain an image and now that I fixed the routing, it is not showing that image. The views are displaying data normally except the image.

Comment: could you put an example to identify the problem by editing your question or create a new one for the new issue ?

Comment: @quoiqueprog you are probably using a relative path for the image so now that the basepath (current URI) has a segment it is relative to that segment now, use an absolute path by using one of the URL helpers

Answer (score 2):

Should be obvious that when there is no other way for laravel to determine which route you want, that it will route to the first one it has in its routing table.

This would be a simple workaround that should illustrate what you are missing.

```
Route::get('/cat/{label}', [BookController::class, 'listbyCat'])-name('bycats');
Route::get('/book/{id}', [BookController::class, 'singlebook'])->name('book');
```

Artisan should be your goto tool whenever you first encounter a problem like this.

```
php artisan route:list
```